# is Windows Phone development possible without installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-phone

I want to learn Windows Phone development. Is it necessary to program apps on Windows 8? Can I not do it on my Windows XP or Windows 7 machine?

Comment: It depends the SDK you would like to use, sdk 7,7.1 would work on windows 7 but SDK 8 wouldn't (that means that you can't develop for windows phone 8 without windows 8 but you can develop for 7.5 and below with windows 7).

Comment: Also, you can't develop for Windows Phone 7 (or Windows Phone 8) on Windows XP.

Answer (score 7):

To Develop to Windows Phone 8 you will need windows 8 pro 64bits. No other OS will work. Also, even if you have Windows 8 Pro 64bits, you may not have access to the emulator, for that you will need a processor that supports hardware-virtualization and SLAT.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with windows phone 7 SDK on windows 7 ;)

Comment: That is called going back.

Answer (score 1):

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) system requirements it states clearly:

- In the BIOS, the following features must be supported:
  Hardware-assisted virtualization. 
     Second Level Address Translation (SLAT). 
     Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).
- 4 GB or more of RAM.
- 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro edition or
  higher.

Answer (score 0):

you can develop windows phone 8 applications only in Windows 8. the emulator doesnt work with any other OS. if your a beginner you can download all the tools including the OS from Microsoft site itself.

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk?logged_in=1

Answer (score 0):

You could try Installing Windows 8 on a Virtual Machine and then Installing Visual Studio 2012 Express along with the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 on your Windows XP or Windows 7 Computer for developing Windows Phone 8 Apps...

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone 8 applications can only be developed on windows 8 64 bit but if you are developing for windows phone 7.1 or 7.5 you can do that on your windows 7 pc but you wont be able to do that in windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

For Developing windows phone 8 apps You must install windows 8 64 bit and visual studio 2012 or higher. also your processor must support Hyper-v and slat all icore(i3,i5,i7) processor of intel support SLAt. but if you don't have window 8 yu can develop apps for window phone 7.1 ,7.5 and 7.8 but this sdk install only visual studio 2010 does not support visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use the web-based [Windows Phone App Studio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/default.htm) to build Windows Phone apps and deploy them onto your phone. You don't need to install anything on your desktop at all.